# Inline SVG versus page rank

Tags: css, search, svg, search-engine, pagerank

I have concerns about placing **big inline SVG vectors** into html. Does this affect **search engines and page rank**? Corresponding to what you can lastly hear about **Code to Text ratio**. I believe inline SVG files should be treated like single line `<img />` but I'm affraid it is not. Can anyone have some relevant knowledge how these are treated?

Of course the purpose i need place them inline is animation and styling directly by root css file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly dont think that this will harm you in the Search Rankings. Search engines would encourage the use of SVG over alternatives such as Canvas.

Google [specifically indexes SVG](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html), weather it is stand-alone or embedded into your HTML.

You can find a full list of [file types indexable by Google Here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35287?hl=en)

Comment: Do you suppose "embedded SVG" implied "inline SVG"?

Comment: Yes, I would imagine so